# Error BadGzipFile when read gz file via python gzip

Tags: python, json, gzip

The source file is json and we zipped it to gz format. The file is good. I am able to open the file with notepad++

```
import gzip

# Open the GZIP file in text mode ('rt')
with gzip.open('example.gz', 'rt') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    print(file_content)
```

The error I get is

> BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'{\n')

I also try to read line by line and get the same error

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('example.gz', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print('got line:', line)
```

This is my sample json data:

```
{
  "metadata_version": 1,
  "created": "2024-01-31T16:02:11.400125+00:00",
  "domain": {
    "name": "myname",
    "version": 1,
    "type": "core"
  },
  "id1": "01HNG439A8M7395MB9CWC4XSKC",
  "id2": {
    "id3": "efbc9315-6a27-455b-9050-02ea08eb1b69",
    "id4": "05933069-eeb5-4801-8801-fdd9819d08bf",
    "id5": "8b642da5-e954-402c-bcb9-a196d594ed62"
  },
  "data": "AAAAAAAA22RzW7CMBCEXyXymVQJNOHnVgGlHIoikvbQ2+IsYMnYdNemQlXfvQ4Q4MB1ZvebWftXVASGQTplzcyrWozEWub9LM8HsUyyNE5TxBjSvoyTJEuyfPUMvXUqOmKJ3x7ZTcChGBmvdUeMNQIps3mznnE"
}
```

Comment: Then it's not a gzipped file. It starts with a brace and a new line, so it is your JSON, not compressed.

Comment: This is my sample json data:
{
  "metadata_version": 1,
  "created": "2024-01-31T16:02:11.400125+00:00",
  "domain": {
    "name": "myname",
    "version": 1,
    "type": "core"
  },
  "id1": "01HNG439A8M7395MB9CWC4XSKC",
  "id2": {
    "id3": "efbc9315-6a27-455b-9050-02ea08eb1b69",
    "id4": "05933069-eeb5-4801-8801-fdd9819d08bf",
    "id5": "8b642da5-e954-402c-bcb9-a196d594ed62"
  },
  "data": "AAAAAAAA22RzW7CMBCEXyXymVQJNOHnVgGlHIoikvbQ2+IsYMnYdNemQlXfvQ4Q4MB1ZvebWftXVASGQTplzcyrWozEWub9LM8HsUyyNE5TxBjSvoyTJEuyfPUMvXUqOmKJ3x7ZTcChGBmvdUeMNQIps3mznnE"
}

Comment: Hi Mark, I just added my sample JSON file. Does the file have any issues?

Comment: "and we zipped it to gz format". No, you didn't.

Comment: Hi Mark, do you add "hen it's not a gzipped file. It starts with a brace and a new line, so it is your JSON, not compressed." as solution. I will mark as answer.You are right, my file is not zipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GZ file is downloaded from AWS S3. When we download the file, AWS unzips it to its original JSON format automatically, and the file name remains myfile.gz. Despite the file name being myfile.gz, it is actually a JSON file, not a GZ file.